# Run code on GPU instead of CPU with detecto

Tags: python, machine-learning, gpu, detecto

I am using machine learning with detecto in Python. However, whenever I run it, I get a warning saying

```
It looks like you're training your model on a CPU. Consider switching to a GPU; otherwise, 
this method can take hours upon hours or even days to finish. For more information, see 
https://detecto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/quickstart.html#technical-requirements
```

I have a GPU in the form of an **Intel(R) HD graphics 4600**, but for some reason the code is running on the CPU. I have checked out the link it gives which says

> By default, Detecto will run all heavy-duty code on the GPU if it’s available and on the CPU otherwise.

It recommends using Google Collab if the computer doesn't have a GPU it can use, but I do have one, and don't want to use Google Collab.

Why is it running on the CPU instead of the GPU? And how can I fix it? The part of my code where I get the warning is

```
losses = fitmodel(loader, Test_dataset, epochs=25, lr_step_size=5, 
learning_rate=0.001, verbose=True)
```

The code does work, however it takes ages to run, so want to be able to run it on the GPU to save time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GPU that `detecto` is referring to would need to be a CUDA capable Nvidia GPU. So your **Intel(R) HD graphics 4600** does not meet this criterion.

`Detecto` uses pytorch internally, whichs GPU support [is based on CUDA](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/). So in order to use a GPU, you would need to move to a machine that has a CUDA capable card

Comment: Thank you so much! Can I change my GPU on my machine? Or is it inbuilt into it? If so I might order one

Comment: Do you have a Laptop or a Desktop ? In the first case note really, the latter case would probably be easy.

Comment: I have a desktop. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: In that case, you will need to check what your mainboard and power supply supports. Probably best to call the customer support of a computer parts store that can help you what can be done